# The delivery may be accelerated?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

I'm writing a quotation and have to estimate a delivery date. My estimate is that we will make the delivery at January 1st. However, this will be impacted by when the project starts. It is in our interest to start as soon as possible and want to express this in a subtle way.

> The delivery date is estimated 01.01.2015, but may be accelerated if the
>   commencement of the project is earlier than 07.07.2014.

According to my good friend, google translate, the "delivery may be accelerated" is the proper way to express this. Google returns 62000 hits for this phrase, so I won't be the first to write it that way, however, I'm not so sure it's the best way. Also "commencement of the project is earlier than" feels a bit wrong. I would actually like to write accelerated there, but in that case I can't use accelerated in the first part..?

I don't want to write: "The delivery date will be impacted by the commencement date" as I want to focus on the positive (it can be done sooner but not later).

Any views on this?

Comment: Why not just "We expect to deliver the _______________ on 01.01.2015, or sooner if if the project starts before 07.07.2014"?

Comment: @BrianDonovan: Good question =)

Comment: see discussion regarding the word `prepone`.  lets make this a thing :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please don’t consider Google Translate your friend. He is a most treacherous and dangerous friendship to make. Consider him more of a casual acquaintance who is occasionally useful in minor matters (and who must always be independently verified).

*Accelerate* is used to refer to making a process move faster, possibly in order to move something ahead in time; but not the action of moving that something up to an earlier point in time itself. So for example, you could say that you were *accelerating* the deadline if you were speeding up the process of the project in order to be done sooner; but if the deadline moves just because the whole project is moved to a different time (for whatever reason, not necessarily to hasten it on), then you wouldn’t say that the deadline is *accelerated*—it’s just moved.

*Move forward* and *push forward* are the most common terms used to describe this type of moving, although this can (in some contexts) create a bit of confusion: *forward* when relating to time can sometimes mean ‘to a later time’ rather than ‘to an earlier time’. A good alternative in your case here would be simply to skip the verbal clause altogether and use *earlier*.

“The commencement of the project” sounds unnecessarily pompous. It is much simpler and easier to use *start* (or even *launch*, since this is a project we’re talking about) instead of *commencement*. And it is much more idiomatic to use *start* as a verb in this sense, instead of saying that the start of something is on a certain day.

Thus, I would say:

> The estimated delivery date is 1 January 2015, or earlier if the project is launched before 7 July 2014.

Comment: _Accelerate_ can also mean _speed up the happening of an event_, which does seem to fit.

Comment: @Frank In a way … but it feels very awkward to me in this context. The OED gives the definition for that sense as “To hasten the occurrence of (an event); to bring (an occurrence) nearer in time, by quickening intervening processes or by shortening the interval”, which is not quite the same. It’s more like _hurry on_ than _move forward_. There is also a sense “To assign to an earlier date, to antedate”, but that is marked as obsolete and rare, and it’s definitely on the wrong side of borderline grammatical to me.

Comment: Thanks for answering Janus =) Would you use launch for smaller projects as well as large ones? The dates I wrote were random, the project will only last a couple of weeks.

Comment: Yes, I might well use _launch_ even for a smaller project, though _start_ might be better: “… or earlier if the project starts before 7 July 2014”.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting _accelerate_ was the perfect choice, just thought it worth to point out that it wasn't the wrong choice.

Comment: @Frank No, I understood what you meant. But to me, _accelerate_ **is** the wrong choice in this context, though not of course in certain others.

Comment: I'll be more blunt. _...not to move a point in time up to an earlier point in time_ is wrong. The OED definition you have provided is exactly that.

Comment: @Frank I don’t think that bit was wrong, but I’ve added some clarifying text to make it clearer what I was referring to. The only OED definition that is exactly that is the one marked as obsolete, which I don’t count exactly because it’s obsolete.

Comment: That would mean that a phrase like _accelerate the debt_ (bringing the maturity date of the whole debt [closer] to today than it currently is, or assign the maturity date to an earlier date) is obsolete. Wow. I no longer get updates to OED since they went on-line so it must be a very recent change of status. I'll take your word for it.

Comment: And up vote your answer too.

Comment: @Frank That seems more like a case of _hurrying on_ the (payment of the) debt to me than just rescheduling something to an earlier date.

Comment: I think you should at least *acknowledge* the possibility of [***prepone***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prepone), even if it does have strong associations with "Indian English". But apart from that I think this is a good summary of the position.

Comment: @Frank I just realised there is a discrepancy between the title and the example sentence in the question. In the title, it says _accelerate the delivery_, which I find perfectly fine (and in line with what you’re saying)—it’s the acceleration of an estimated delivery _date_ that I find ungrammatical.